# I don't understand why it doesn't display the image

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i have a problem with displaying the image, i searched for a solution, but it seems that the problem persist.

```
My code looks like this:

    const IntoBanner= ({ 
            [...]
            img,
            alt,
            [...]
        }) => {
        return (
            <>
              [...]
                <Image src={img} alt={alt} />
              [...]
     
            </>
        );
    };

export default IntoBanner;
```

The file from which retrived the info looks like this

```
export const homeObjOne = {
    [...]
    img: require('../../images/svg-1.svg'),
    alt: 'Image', 
    [...]
};
```

I want to specify that the directory are set correctly, because from that area it also take over the texts, the only problem is the image, the location for the image is correct, but i don't understand why it doesn't display it on the site..

Comment: Instead of using `require('../../images/svg-1.svg'),` try removing the `require` method and just do `'../../images/svg-1.svg'`.

Comment: Hey @PerplexingParadox , i have already tried this. the image folder is inside the src/ folder, the location from where will have to take that image is correct, but i don't understand why it doesn't display the image.

Comment: I solved, i just created a import.